# Hilbert's syzygy theorem in the analytic setting

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

If $X$ is a projective variety then Hilbert's syzygy theorem says that any coherent sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$ modules has a finite resolution by locally free modules.

By GAGA, I believe this should imply that over any smooth complex submanifold $X$ of $\mathbb CP^n$, a coherent sheaf of modules over the sheaf of holomorphic functions has a finite resolution by holomorphic vector bundles.

Assuming what I said is correct, is there a direct proof of this in the analytic setting?  Also, is the analytic statement true for more general complex manifolds (e.g. Kahler)?

Note: this is a crosspost from [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/154092/12617).

Comment: I don't know much about this topic but I think you mean finite resolutions. Infinite ones should always exist. Anyway, nice question.

Comment: @Marek you're right, thanks for the correction.  I have edited it accordingly.

Comment: Dear Eric, Since this has been answered in the comments on MO, you might want to say so here (to save duplication of effort; indeed, I was about to write something similar to the comment on MO, before thinking I should check there first).  Regards,